# Distance to origin from curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Hello all I am trying to redo a problem I had and I am stumped for some reasons. I just want to find the maximum and minimal distance from the curve $$7x^2-6xy+7y^2-6=0$$ to the origin. But I want to do this in the most efficient way as well.

I calculated $$f_x=14x-6y$$ and $$f_y=14y-6x$$ and setting these to zero and solving gives a unique solution of $x=y=0$
But I know I can't just plug this in to test.

( And I am also using the fact that I can max/min the square of the distance function as my second constraint that is $d=x^2+y^2$)

Now if I try Lagrange I get something along the lines of $$(14x-6y)=\lambda 2x$$
and $$(14y-6x)= \lambda 2y$$

But I am having a mental block from exam times and I just can't figure out how I can go about simplifying this. Am I on the right track? Thanks

Comment: I don't think Lagrange is very effective here. Do you know symmetrical matrix or quadratic form? By applying an orthogonal  transformation, you'll find the curve is in fact an ellipse viewed from a proper coordinate system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your system of equations, note that $14- 6(y/x) = 2\lambda = 14-6(x/y)$.  Thus, $x^2 = y^2$, and you need to find the points on your curve where $x = \pm y$.

Comment: ohh write I need to multiply both equations by either x and y respectively, thanks for jogging my train of thought

Comment: And than would I plug in f(x,x) and f(x,-x) and find those criticals?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to evaluate at the chosen points to find the extreme values.

Comment: Thanks, when I plug into f(x,x) I seem to get one of the correct answers, but I can't seem to get it to work with f(x,-x)?

Comment: Those $x$ need to be solutions to $7x^2 - 6x(-x) + 7(-x)^2 = 6$, instead, perhaps?

Comment: Yea i got it, thanks sir

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2= 1 , $ with  the  condition   $4AC - B^2 > 0$ ,  is an ellipse rotated about the origin.

Hence

$$ 7x^2 - 6xy + 7y^2 = 6 $$

is an ellipse as specified above.

Polar coordinates:

$$  x = r\cos(\phi) ; y = r\sin(\phi) .$$

Inserting:

$$ 7r^2- 6r^2\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi) = 6 ,$$

$$ r^2 (7 - 3\sin(2\phi))  = 6 $$

Extremal values of the parenthesis:

Min: $ \sin(2\phi) = 1$,  for  $2 \phi = π/2 + k(2π),   k= 1,2, ....$

Max: 
$\sin (2\phi) = -1$, for  $2\phi = (3/2)π + k(2π), k= 1,2,...$

$Finally:$

Maximum distance square from the origin:

Max: $ r^2 = 3/2 $,  at  $\phi = π/4 $, 
and $\phi = π/4 + π. $

Min:   $r^2 = 3/5,$  at $ \phi = (3/4)π$, 
and $\phi = (3/4)π + π.$

The major axis of the ellipse:

$a = \sqrt{3/2} ,$

the minor axis of the ellipse:

$b = \sqrt{3/5}.$

Comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

more quick way is : $-(x^2+y^2)\le -2xy \le x^2+y^2 \implies 4(x^2+y^2)\le 7x^2-6xy+7y^2 \le 10(x^2+y^2) \implies 4(x^2+y^2)\le 6 \cap 10(x^2+y^2) \ge 6 \implies \dfrac{3}{5} \le x^2+y^2 \le \dfrac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

In your example $$d(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 = \frac{6}{7}(1+xy).$$ I believe the right hand side is maximum when $x=y$, so the point on the curve where $x=y$ is at a maximum distance from the origin.

Answer (score 0):

W/O using calculus,

We have $\dfrac{x^2+y^2}6=\dfrac{xy+1}7=k$(say)

We need the extreme values of  $x^2+y^2=6k\ge0$

We have $xy=7k-1$

Using $(x\pm y)^2\ge0\iff x^2+y^2\ge\pm2xy\iff6k\ge\pm2(7k-1)$

Taking the $'+'$ sign,$6k\ge2(7k-1)\iff2\ge(14-6)k\iff k\le1/4$

Taking the $'-'$ sign,$6k\ge-2(7k-1)\iff20k\ge2\iff k\ge1/10$